# Getting Error loading layout while using Dash Framework in Python

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

While running this code, I get "Error loading layout".
I'm using the dash framework in python.
What I'm trying to do is a dashboard with a set of parameters (ex: choosing the x-axis, y-axis)
I tried setting debug to true, but it shows me 0 errors.

```
app.layout = html.Div(

    children=[
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.H1(
                    children="Poverty Lens", className="header-title"
                ),
                html.P(
                    children="Visual Analytics",
                    className="header-description",
                ),
    
            ],
            className="header",
        ),
    
        dcc.Loading(
            id="loading-1", fullscreen=True, children=html.Div(id="loading-output-1")
        ),
    
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.H2("Visualization Options",
                        style={'text-align': 'center', 'color': 'grey', 'fontSize': 18, 'marginBottom': '15px',
                               'marginLeft': '5px'}),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
    
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="X-Axis", className="menu-title", id='x-axis-title'),
                        dcc.Dropdown(id="x-axis",
                                     options=([x] for x in newCountry),
                                     multi=False,
                                     value='',
                                     clearable=False,
                                     className="dropdown",
                                     ),
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Y-Axis", className="menu-title", id="y-axis-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(id="y-axis",
                                     options=[{"label": "Access to electricity", "value": 'Access to electricity'},
                                              {"label": "healthy_unaffordable_share",
                                               "value": 'healthy_unaffordable_share'},
                                              ],
                                     multi=False,
                                     value='loan_amount',
                                     clearable=False,
                                     className="dropdown",
    
                                     ),
                    ]
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div("Aggregate", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_aggregation",
                                     options=['sum', 'avg'],
                                     multi=False,
                                     value='sum',
                                     clearable=False,
                                     className="dropdown",
                                     ),
                    ]
                ),
    
            ],
            className="menu",
    
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
    
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Select Sorting", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_sorting",
                                     options=[
                                         {"label": "Top", "value": 'Top'},
                                         {"label": "Bottom", "value": 'Bottom'},
                                     ],
                                     multi=False,
                                     value='',
                                     className="dropdown",
                                     ),
                    ]
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Select Value", className="menu-title"),
                        daq.NumericInput(id='slct_nvalue',
                                         value=10,
                                         size='256px'
                                         ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
    
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Select Order", className="menu-radio"),
                        dcc.RadioItems(id="slct_order",
                                       options=[
                                           {"label": "Ascending", "value": 'Ascending'},
                                           {"label": "Descending", "value": 'Descending'}
                                       ],
                                       value='Ascending',
                                       className="radio",
                                       )
                    ],
                ),
    
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Date Range", className="menu-date"),
                        dcc.DatePickerRange(
                            id="date-range",
                            display_format='Y',
                            min_date_allowed='2017',
                            max_date_allowed='2020',
                            start_date='2017',
                            end_date='2020',
                            className="date",
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
    
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.H2("Recommendation Options",
                        style={'text-align': 'center', 'color': 'grey', 'fontSize': 18, 'marginBottom': '15px',
                               'marginLeft': '5px'}),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
    
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Scope", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_scope", options=[{"label": "Country", "value": 'Entity'},
                                                               {"label": "Year", "value": 'Year'},
                                                               ],
                                     multi=False,
                                     value='',
                                     clearable=True,
                                     className="dropdown",
                                     disabled=False
    
                                     ),
                    ]
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Specify Scope ", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(id="specify_scope", options=[],
                                     multi=True,
                                     value='',
                                     clearable=True,
                                     className="dropdown",
                                     disabled=True
    
                                     ),
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            className="menu",
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    id='bar_div',
                    children=dcc.Graph(id='bar', figure={}, ),
                    className='card',
                ),
                html.Div(
                    id='rec1_bar_div',
                    children=dcc.Graph(id='rec1_bar', figure={}, ),
                    className='card',
                ),
                html.Div(
                    id='rec2_bar_div',
                    children=dcc.Graph(id='rec2_bar', figure={}, ),
                    className='card',
                ),
                html.Div(
                    id='rec3_bar_div',
                    children=dcc.Graph(id='rec3_bar', figure={}, ),
                    className='card',
                ),
                html.Div(
                    id='rec4_bar_div',
                    children=dcc.Graph(id='rec4_bar', figure={}, ),
                    className='card',
                )]
        )
    ]

)
```

I couldn't figure out what's missing.

Is there an editor that detects the issues in the embeded HTML code?

Comment: Tried to run and I did not see any error.

Answer (score 0):

Comment each div out until you find the one that causes the problem.
The answer is that dcc.Dropdown was given the wrong type for options. It expects a dictionary.

```
                   dcc.Dropdown(
                        id="x-axis",
                        options=([x] for x in newCountry), <-- Error
                        multi=False,
                        value="",
                        clearable=False,
                        className="dropdown",
                    ),
```